# Child process memory free problem with execvp

Tags: c, valgrind

The following code is from the book "Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces".  The code is confusing me.
I know `execvp` never returns when it works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        // fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        // child: redirect standard output to a file
        close(STDOUT_FILENO); 
        open("./p4.output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);

        // now exec "wc"...
        char *myargs[3];
        myargs[0] = strdup("wc");   // program: "wc" (word count)
        myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c"); // argument: file to count
        myargs[2] = NULL;           // marks end of array
        execvp(myargs[0], myargs);  // runs word count
    } else {
        // parent goes down this path (original process)
        int wc = wait(NULL);
    assert(wc >= 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use Valgrind to check for memory leaks.  The above code does no memory leak. When I delete the `execvp` line, it will detect definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks.  Why is this?

Valgrind command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

when I use command valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full ./p4

```
==15091== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15091== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15091== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15091== Command: ./p4
==15091==
==15092== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15092== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15092== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15092== Command: /usr/bin/wc p4.c
==15092==
==15092==
==15092== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15092==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15092==   total heap usage: 36 allocs, 36 frees, 8,809 bytes allocated
==15092==
==15092== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15092==
==15092== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15092== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==15091==
==15091== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15091==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15091==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15091==
==15091== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15091==
==15091== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15091== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[root cpu-api]#
```

no matter how many bytes I malloc,the heap summary always says:
==15092==   total heap usage: 36 allocs, 36 frees, 8,809 bytes allocated

Comment: Do you understand where the memory allocation occurs?  Do you realize that the memory allocation is not necessary?  Mercifully, you aren't expected to free all allocated memory before you use `execvp()` (or any of the other `exec*()` functions).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your reply,I read the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html,still don't quite understand.Is there an article about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What's "definitely lost" memory?

First of all, let's discuss what Valgrind reports as "definitely lost": Valgrind will report allocated memory as "definitely lost" if all references to the allocated memory are lost before the termination of the program. In other words, if your program reaches a state in which there is allocated memory that cannot be freed because no valid pointers to it exists, this will count as "definitely lost".

This means that a program like this:

```
int main(void) {
    char *buf = malloc(10);
    // ...
    exit(0);
}
```

will cause *no error* from Valgrind, while a program like this:

```
void func(void) {
    char *buf = malloc(10);
    // ...
} // memory is definitely lost here

int main(void) {
    func();
    exit(0);
}
```

will cause a "definitely lost" error.

Why is the first version ok for Valgrind? It's because memory is *always* freed by the system on program exit. If you keep using an allocated chunk of memory until the end of your program, there really is no need to explicitly call `free()` on it, and it can be considered as just a waste of time. For this reason, if you don't free some allocated block while still holding a reference to it, Valgrind assumes that you did so to avoid an "useless" `free()` because you are smart and know that the OS is going to take care of it anyway.

If however you forget to `free()` something, and lose every reference to it, then Valgrind warns you, because you should have `free()`d the memory. If you don't, and the program keeps running, then the same thing happens each time the buggy block is entered, and you end up wasting memory. This is what is called a "memory leak". A very simple example is the following:

```
void func(void) {
    char *buf = malloc(10);
    // ...
} // memory is definitely lost here

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        func();
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

This program will make your machine run out of memory and could ultimately end up killing or freezing your system (warning: do not test this if you don't want to risk freezing your PC). If you instead correctly call `free(buf)` before the end of `func`, then the program keeps running indefinitely without a problem.

### What happens in your program

Now let's see where you are allocating memory and where the variables holding the references are declared. The only part of the program that is allocating memory is inside the `if (rc == 0)` block, through `strdup`, here:

```
char *myargs[3];
myargs[0] = strdup("wc");   // program: "wc" (word count)
myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c"); // argument: file to count
```

The two calls to `strdup()` duplicate the string and allocate new memory to do so. Then, you save a reference to the newly allocated memory in the `myargs` array, which is declared **inside the `if` block**. If your program exits the block without freeing the allocated memory, then those references will be lost, and there will be no way for your program to free the memory.

**With `execvp()`**: your child process is replaced by the new process (`wc p4.c`), and the memory space of the parent process is thrown away by the operating system (for Valgrind, this is exactly the same as program termination). This memory is *not* counted as lost by Valgrind, because references to the allocated memory are still present when `execvp()` is called. NOTE: this is *not* becaue you pass the pointers to allocated memory to `execvp()`, it's because the original program effectively terminates and memory is retained by the OS.

**Without `execvp()`**: your child process continues execution, and right after it exits the code block where `myargs` is defined, it *loses any reference to the allocated memory* (since `myargs[0]` and `myargs[1]` were the only references). Valgrind then correctly reports this as "definitely lost", 8 bytes (3 for `"wc"` and 5 for `"p4.c"`) in 2 blocks (2 allocations). The same thing happens if the call to `execvp()` fails for whatever reason.

### Additional considerations

To be fair, there is no real need to call `strdup()` in the program you show. It's not like those strings need to be copied because they are used somewhere else (or anything like that). The code could have simply been:

```
myargs[0] = "wc";   // program: "wc" (word count)
myargs[1] = "p4.c"; // argument: file to count
```

In any case, a good practice when using the `exec*()` family of functions, is to put an `exit()` directly after it, to ensure the program doesn't keep running in case the `exec*()` fails. Something like this:

```
execvp(myargs[0], myargs); 
perror("execvp failed");
exit(1);
```

Comment: thanks.Your first two example all will detected 10 bytes in 1 blocks deinitely lost with vagrind 3.13.0

Comment: I agree with you that a memory leak will only occur if the memory is not released in the long run process. If the program finishes executing and exits quickly, there is no memory leak.As a good practice, releasing memory after using it is not considered useless.

Comment: @J.Doe it is, by some C programmers. If you have a big complex structure that you need to use from start to finish of your program you don't need to free() it. You only waste time doing so, as the memory will be retained by the OS anyway. I'm not saying that you should do it, I'm saying that some might consider it useless and that it's not really needed.

Comment: read your answer several times,I found a mistake.Without execvp(),it will detect 8 bytes in 2 blocks,it is wc(3) plus p4.c(5),not the pointer.I delete myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c");then valgrind tells:definitely lost: 3 bytes in 1 blocks

Comment: as you say,with execvp,there is a reference in execvp,but when I add this line below myargs[2] = NULL,valgrind still get no memory leak.        int *p = (int *)malloc(10 *sizeof(int));

Comment: @J.Doe the fact that *with `execvp`* the leak is detected is **not** because you "pass the reference" to `execvp`. It's because the whole memory space of your program is destroyed by the kernel. It's like your program is exiting. Allocated memory is still reachable so Valgrind doesn't report that as an error. Values are *not* passed by reference to the program that is executed through `execvp`, they are copied on it's stack by the kernel. You can add as many `malloc()` a you want before `execvp`, and there will be no leak detected.

Comment: @J.Doe also, I corrected my two examples to use `exit(0)` since `valgrind` has an hard time detecting return from `main()`. An explicit exit generates no error (no "definitely lost") in the first example of mine. Let me know if there's still something that is not clear.

Comment: you were right,first example will get still reachable.one more question:here exit and return make a big difference,why does this ?

Comment: @J.Doe I cannot say *for sure*, but Valgrind could have issues in detecting a `return` from `main`. Detecting a call to `exit()` is much easier since Valgrind can easily hook the function (same thing for `exec*()`). Nonetheless, if I recall correctly (can't test right now) I have a more complex program where Valgrind correctly detects no "definitely lost" even if I do `return 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. Which means the program that is currently being run by the calling process to be replaced with a new program, with newly initialised stack, heap, and (initialised and uninitialised) data segments.

In the child process, when you are calling `execvp()`

```
execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
```

the child process replaced with new process (assuming `execvp()` is success) and the memory allocated in the child process

```
    myargs[0] = strdup("wc");   // program: "wc" (word count)
    myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c"); // argument: file to count
```

will be effectively reclaimed by new process. So, when you have `execvp()` in child process, `valgrind` is not reporting any memory leak.

> *`When I delete the execvp line, it will detect definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks. Why is this?`*

From [strdup()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup): *[emphasis added]*

> > char * strdup(const char *str1);
> >             (dynamic memory TR)
> >
> > Returns a pointer to a null-terminated byte string, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by str1. **The returned pointer must be passed to free to avoid a memory leak.**

So, when there is no `execvp()` call in your program, the child process is leaking the memory allocated by `strdup()`. To fix this problem, free the memory allocated by `strdup()` may be after `execvp()`, so that if `execvp()` by chance fail or you explicitly remove `execvp()` call from your program, it should not leak memory:

```
    myargs[0] = strdup("wc");   // program: "wc" (word count)
    myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c"); // argument: file to count
    myargs[2] = NULL;           // marks end of array
    execvp(myargs[0], myargs);  // runs word count
    printf ("execvp failed\n"); // You may want to print the errno as well
    free (myargs[0]);
    free (myargs[1]);
```

Note that there is no need to allocate memory and copy string literals to that memory. You can directly assign the string literals to `myargs`, like this:

```
    myargs[0] = "wc";
    myargs[1] = "p4.c";
```

Comment: Marco Bonelli's answer say there is a reference in execvp,I add one line below myargs[2],using valgrind still get no memory leak,        int *p = (int *)malloc(10 *sizeof(int));.

Comment: still can not understand,why there is no memory leak in child process.

Comment: @J.DoeThe first paragraph of my answer explains why valgrind is not reporting the memory leak.